# Requesting Data for call back url

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

I am new on working third party API, working on GUPSHUP API and with the help of guzzle I am sending msg to whatsapp but for receiving the message from callback url to my controller what should I use.
Notes-> Callback url which i added on is webhook call back URL , Now when any event happened on that url
how to receive that   in my laravel controller, i search all the places where they suggested  call webhook client server put a route

```
Route::webhooks('webhook-receiving-url');
```

in this i have to put my call back url . but i want to receive this call back url in controller , how to  do this , please help me out